How do I edit a public function in Wordpress theme via functions.php
I have a public function on a page in my Wordpress theme:
class Freeio_Elementor_Freeio_Favorite_Tabs extends Elementor\Widget_Base {

    public function get_tab_options() {
        $options = [
            'service' => esc_html__('Service', 'freeio'),
            'project' => esc_html__('Project', 'freeio'),
            'job' => esc_html__('Job', 'freeio'),
            'employer' => esc_html__('Employer', 'freeio'),
            'freelancer' => esc_html__('Freelancer', 'freeio'),
        ];
        return $options;
    }
}

And I would like to edit the function so it is:
    public function get_tab_options() {
        $options = [
            'service' => esc_html__('Service', 'freeio'),
            'employer' => esc_html__('Employer', 'freeio'),
            'freelancer' => esc_html__('Freelancer', 'freeio'),
        ];
        return $options;
    }

I have a Child Theme with functions.php.
How do I override the get_tab_options function with my custom version?
Thank you

Your "public function" is actually a "class method" with "public visibility". If hooks aren't being used, the only way to override this would be to create a new class, however I don't know how class loading works in this scenario, so I don't know if it is possible.

class Your_Custom_Class extends Freeio_Elementor_Freeio_Favorite_Tabs { your function }
